# Multiple File Columns on a list

Tags: list, column, attachments

A client of mine need a list where each item can have 3 attachments. Each attachment would be tied to a column.

For example, if the list is called "Meetings", it would have two file columns; "Minutes" and "Agenda". The edit form would have the usual fields for title and Description plus two fields for uploading files.

I have searched for how to implement this and have not come across anyone who may have implemented this.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hi @adaptive, did you find a solution for this? I too have a requirement for multiple attachment/file columns in a list and unfortunately document sets don't suit the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Would using document sets be out of the question? You could create one that had all the properties of a meeting, and under that upload the needed files. It gets all of the grouping and metadata sharing that you would with a single listitem for everything.

See: http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/Blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=462

Comment: Unfortunately no, this is not quite what I'm looking for. It is infact a very interesting approach. Thanks for the guidance though.